# Rebase local commits on remote subtree update

Tags: git, git-rebase, monorepo, git-subtree

I'm trying to build a monorepo that has subtrees to other projects I'm using. In these subtrees I want to make some customizations to fit my monorepo project.

When changes occur on the remote (original) projects of the subtree I want to pull these changes into my monorepo. And to avoid lots of merge-conflicts instead of merging I would like to rebase my changes onto the updates from remote.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any resource yet that would describe if this is actually possible and how to do this. Also I couldn't yet figure out a solution myself from the git docs.

Here is a diagram of how I imagine the history to be:

[image: History of fileA before and after rebase on repos mono and library]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such tool and you will have to write it yourself. Remember that the history in a Git repository *is* the commits in the repository, so if you don't like the history, you must replace existing commits with new-and-improved commits that form the history that you do like.

Comment: I've now went with a little bit easier idea as this seems really hard to do. Will leave it open though for someone in the future with more brain than me to maybe answer it 